# Praying while driving?

Tags: salat, travelling

Some times i travel for long journeys where i am not able to stop and pray, would my salat be accepted if i pray while driving on high speed highways?

or shall i pray and repeat the prayer at home or pray once i arrive home

Brother please give advice from quran and hadith

Plus happy Eid to every one

Comment: That's if you don't get pulled over by the police of the respective country, especially in Western countries, doing such an activity while driving is considered "driving without due caress" in quite a few countries

Comment: As in you're the one driving and should be paying  at least some attention to the road, or as in you're a passenger and can actually focus on your prayer without risking fiery crashing death for all involved?

Comment: Sorry Sammaye and @goldPseudo, to be more clear as in by praying while driving i will not be able to bow down, at least i can recite the stages of the prayer without the physical movement to concentrate on the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer your question logically.

When you are praying, your **maximum** attention (if not *all*) should be towards your Salah.

So when I am praying:

- can I watch TV? **NO**
- can I have a phone conversation? **NO**
- can I make a sandwich? **NO**
- can I wash dishes? **NO**
- can I iron my clothes? **NO**
- can I look outside the window and appreciate how Allah has created wind which moves the leaves and the weather is really nice? **NO**

When I cannot do any of the above tasks while praying (because they take my attention *away* from praying) how can *driving a car* be allowed?

---

Now about what you wrote in the beginning of your question:

> Some times i travel for long journeys where i am not able to stop and pray

You just have to decide what is more important. That's what life is all about.

Answer (score 3):

Standing is an essential part of prayer.  But if one can't stand and pray, then they're permitted to sit and pray, and if that's not possible, then laying on the side or whatever is also allowed.  The Prophet is reported to have said:

> **"Pray standing and if you can't, pray sitting and if you cannot do
>   even that, then pray Lying on your side."**

It's an authentic *hadith* and is collected in numerous books, including [(Sahih al-Bukhari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/18/37)

Now the issue comes down to is whether the exemption is due to illness or being in a situation where one cant stand.

The context of the narration was in regards to illness.  However, the statement of the Prophet was in general speech.  So therefore, it can be taken without being it restricted to illness.  And this is in regards to sitting in a car.

Now driving, well, you can pray while driving, but think of the safety concerns.  Would you take the risk?  Can you pull over without getting out of the car?

You cannot be excused to missing the prayer just because you're driving, unless of course it's out of forgetfulness or oversleeping.

So try to use your critical thinking inshaAllah.

Allaho Alim.